# How to connect tableau with Google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tabpy

We have tabpy running on Google colab on port number 9004.
We are not able to connect to the tabpy service running in Google colab from tabpy analytics extension that has been set up on tableau locally.
The issue seems to be with the IP address for the service as there are no public IPs.

I have gone through the documentation.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NO, please export your colab output into CSV and then connect that file with Tableau